# Hibernate query.list() does not respond in second attempt

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am working on a REST server which accepts and returns JSON data. For a particular input values(from input JSON) Hibernate (integrated with Spring) query the database and send JSON back to Rest Controller. Client application is designed to have timeout of 5 sec, for reading response, which cannot be altered.

Now the problem is sometimes (not always but mostly) the Hibernate is unable to process data within given time limit thus time out error is received on client side. The logger just before query.list() worked but next logger wasn't printed. On manual run of SQl returned data in part of second. All data manipulation logic is written in DAOImpl method thus there is no loop elsewhere. Since tables corresponding to sql queries mentioned in code are child tables therefore i dont see mapping related issues with these. To more surprise, method returns data sometimes for same input but fails when called later while browsing the application

I checked with other post on net to use full constructor in bean classes and to have lazy loading. Both are true in my case. Below is one of the DAOImpl method causing this problem. Here i have to query 2 tables (which doesn't have much data, approx 20 entries in each table), add all data to a json array and send back.

```
@Override
       public String getOfferOnRuleNameBalance(String inputJsonString) {
        JSONObject saveJsonObject = new JSONObject(inputJsonString);
        String ruleName    =   saveJsonObject.getString("rulename");
        int currentAccountBalance    =   saveJsonObject.getInt("currentAccountBalance");
        Session session1 = getSession();
        Criteria criteria =session1.createCriteria(PaymentPlanOffers.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("rulename", ruleName));
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<PaymentPlanOffers> offerList=criteria.list();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        for(PaymentPlanOffers object:offerList)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject1 =new JSONObject();
            jsonObject1.put("instAmount",object.getAmountPercent());
            jsonObject1.put("instNumber", object.getNumInstallment());
            jsonObject1.put("frequency", object.getFrequency());
            jsonObject1.put("offerId", object.getId());
            jsonObject1.put("offerName", object.getOfferName());
            jsonObject1.put("active", object.isActive());
            jsonObject1.put("accepted", object.isAccepted());
            jsonObject1.put("totalAmount", currentAccountBalance);
            jsonObject1.put("startDate", object.getStartDate());
            jsonObject1.put("endDate", object.getEndDate());
            jsonArray.put(jsonObject1);
        }

        Criteria criteria2 =session1.createCriteria(CustomPlanOffer.class);
        criteria2.add(Restrictions.eq("rulename", ruleName));
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<CustomPlanOffer> customOfferList=criteria2.list();
        for(CustomPlanOffer object:customOfferList)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject1 =new JSONObject();
            jsonObject1.put("instAmount", object.getAvgInstallment());
            jsonObject1.put("instNumber", object.getNumOfInstallment());
            jsonObject1.put("frequency", object.getFrequency());
            jsonObject1.put("offerId", object.getId());
            jsonObject1.put("offerName", object.getName());
            jsonObject1.put("active", object.isActive());
            jsonObject1.put("accepted", object.isAccepted());
            jsonObject1.put("totalAmount", object.getTotalPaymentAmount());
            jsonObject1.put("startDate", object.getStartDate());
            jsonObject1.put("endDate", object.getEndDate());
            jsonArray.put(jsonObject1);
        }

        JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
        mainObj.put("allOffers", jsonArray);
        session1.close();
        return mainObj.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to upgrade hibernate to the latest version! that solved the problem!